# Row-wise linear regression and prediction in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have two country data sets, the first one goes from 2012 to 2020, and looks like this:

```
> head(y)
              Country 2012 2013 2014 2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
1         Afghanistan    0  0.0    0    0  0.00  4.00  7.00 22.00 26.00
2             Albania    0  0.0    0   35 80.20 85.30 85.50 95.00 98.38
3             Algeria    0  0.0    0    0  3.62 30.49 52.84 53.63 76.18
4             Andorra   50 50.0   50   50 50.00 85.00 85.00 85.00 85.00
5              Angola    7  7.0    7    7  8.00  8.00  8.00 18.00 30.00
6 Antigua and Barbuda   65 78.6   80   98 99.00 99.00 99.00 99.00 99.00
```

and the second goes from 2012 to 2030, and looks like this:

```
> head(x)
  CountryName CountryCode CountryCodeID ProductID     Y2012 Y2013 Y2014    Y2015     Y2016     Y2017     Y2018     Y2019     Y2020     Y2021     Y2022     Y2023     Y2024     Y2025     Y2026     Y2027     Y2028     Y2029     Y2030
1     Antigua          AA           157    178271 98.000000 98.00 98.00 98.35281  99.22350  99.30797  99.38018  99.44286  99.49796  99.54694  99.59088  99.63063 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
2     Albania          AB           158    178271 99.000000 99.00 99.00 99.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
3      Angola          AG           161    178271 47.000000 53.00 46.00 60.00000  70.12252  78.48148  84.95833  89.19728  92.40534  95.10876  96.64146  97.54840  98.10920  98.46371  99.36144  99.42651  99.48353  99.53406  99.57929
4  Azerbaijan          AJ           163    178271 96.500000 96.90 97.10 97.30000  98.23938  98.78344  99.10162 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
5     Algeria          AL           164    178271  1.142043  6.00 23.23 46.00000  56.33254  66.41615  75.59252  82.67079  88.15954  91.56166  94.41373  96.92251  98.01697  98.65143  99.02451 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
6     Armenia          AM           165    178271 96.300000 97.68 98.80 99.90000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
```

I want to run a linear regression like `lm(y ~ x)` for each country, for dates between 2012 and 2020, and then predict `y` for 2021 up to 2030 based on `x` of the same period.

Can anyone help me achieve this? Since I have 139 countries (rows), it fastidious to extract each country from both data sets and combine them in one data frame and then run the regression and the prediction, something more efficient would help a long way.

Comment: what are your `x` and `y` in the model

Comment: @Mike `y` is a row (country) from data frame `y` from 2012 to 2020, `x` is the corresponding row (country) from data frame `x` from 2012 to 2020.

Comment: can you use dput to share your data, `dput(head(x))` and `dput(head(y))` and then copy the output into your question.

Comment: You need to have consistent columns to be able to do predictions. Also, you cannot fit a regression with only one row. You might want to read up on regression analysis or take some online class/tutorial.

Comment: @Baraliuh I am going to modify the names in the first data frame and change the order to make it similar in both data frames. Why can I not regress one series (row) over another one? I just need someone to help me do row-wise regression and prediction.

Comment: that is unnecessary. you can't regress one row at a time because your model will fit perfectly and not be a useful statistic but that is not what you want. in your case you have to subset to country, transpose the data to a long format by year in both datasets and run a regression which eliminates the one row issue

Comment: @Mike Can you please show me how to do this in an answer?

Comment: the new answer below is pretty comprehensive, if that does not work for you I will post a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's better to convert your data into tidy format so that there's one row for each year's observation. I'll demonstrate it on a simulated data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

N_COUNTRIES <- 3
YEARS <- 2012:2020
N_YEARS <- length(YEARS)

# simulate x data
countries <- LETTERS[1:N_COUNTRIES]
mat_x <- matrix(runif(N_COUNTRIES*N_YEARS, 0, 100), nrow = N_COUNTRIES)
colnames(mat_x) <- YEARS
df_x <- bind_cols(country = countries, mat_x)

# simulate y data
mat_y <- matrix(runif(N_COUNTRIES*N_YEARS, 0, 50), nrow = N_COUNTRIES)
colnames(mat_y) <- paste0("Y", YEARS)
df_y <- bind_cols(
  country = countries,
  some_other_column = sample(1:100, N_COUNTRIES), mat_y
)

# convert df_x to long format
df_x_long <- 
  df_x %>% 
  pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "x") %>% 
  mutate(across(year, as.numeric))

head(df_x_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   country  year     x
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        2012  67.6
#> 2 A        2013  71.9
#> 3 A        2014  48.7
#> 4 A        2015  20.0
#> 5 A        2016  13.3
#> 6 A        2017  62.4

# convert df_y to long format
df_y_long <- 
  df_y %>% 
  select(country, starts_with("Y")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "y") %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub("^Y", "", year)))
```

Now it's easy to merge x and y observations together.

```r
# join
df_xy_long <- inner_join(df_x_long, df_y_long, by = c("country", "year"))

head(df_xy_long)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   country  year     x     y
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        2012  67.6  13.6
#> 2 A        2013  71.9  19.5
#> 3 A        2014  48.7  35.0
#> 4 A        2015  20.0  31.9
#> 5 A        2016  13.3  16.7
#> 6 A        2017  62.4  47.4
```

Having this we can use `tidyr::nest()` to kind of put observations for each country into separate boxes to then run `lm` on each of them.

```r
# nest and model
df_xy_nested <- 
  df_xy_long %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(model = list(lm(y ~ x, data = data))) %>% 
  ungroup()

head(df_xy_nested)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   country data             model 
#>   <chr>   <list>           <list>
#> 1 A       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>  
#> 2 B       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>  
#> 3 C       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>
```

Each element in the `data` column is a dataframe itself and each element in the `model` column is an `lm` model.

```r
df_xy_nested$data[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>    year     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2012  67.6 13.6 
#> 2  2013  71.9 19.5 
#> 3  2014  48.7 35.0 
#> 4  2015  20.0 31.9 
#> 5  2016  13.3 16.7 
#> 6  2017  62.4 47.4 
#> 7  2018  38.1 40.9 
#> 8  2019  96.1 36.6 
#> 9  2020  24.8  2.57

df_xy_nested$model[[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            x  
#>     19.3173       0.1587
```

You might want to extract model coefficients like this:

```r
df_xy_nested %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    coef_intercept = model$coefficients[[1]],
    coef_x = model$coefficients[[2]]
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   country data             model  coef_intercept  coef_x
#>   <chr>   <list>           <list>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>             19.3  0.159 
#> 2 B       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>             29.9 -0.161 
#> 3 C       <tibble [9 × 3]> <lm>             18.3  0.0427
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

For some more details about modeling on nested data I'd recommend you to read:

- [a paragraph on rowwise() documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html#modelling) (very short)
- [a chapter in R4DS](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) (not short at all)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to add the predictions to the data frame, or to create a new data frame for them?

Comment: @SaïdMaanan It is described briefly in this chapter https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html#modelling . Does this answer your question?